# Django can't login after save

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have TokenAuthentification on my `django-rest-server`.
After registration `login` works perfectly, but when I call update with old fields, I can't login anymore (**Unable to log in with provided credentials**) in response. What am I doing wrong?

update code:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name')
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email')
    password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password')
    profile_photo = serializers.ImageField(source='details_sample.profile_photo', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'profile_photo', 'phone')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        if validated_data.get('user') is not None:
            instance.user.set_password(validated_data['user'].get('password', instance.user.password))
            instance.username = validated_data['user'].get('username', instance.user.password)
            instance.first_name = validated_data['user'].get('first_name', instance.user.password)
            instance.last_name = validated_data['user'].get('last_name', instance.user.password)
            instance.user.save()

        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

login url:

```
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

token creation:

```
@receiver(post_init, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: what do you mean by can't login anymore?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki added. "Unable to log in with provided credentials." in response. But username and password is correct for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think your trouble here:

```
instance.user.set_password(validated_data['user'].get('password', instance.user.password))
#                                                                 ^^^^^
```

try to replace:

```
password = validated_data['user'].get('password', None)
if password:
      instance.user.set_password(password)
```